# Ask Ubuntu badges are not displayed in 'my trophies'

Tags: accomplishments

I have installed the 0.2 version of the accomplishments (and verified that this is the version running).

The badges can be seen in the 'opportunities' but not in 'my trophies'.

I have entered the URL of by Ask Ubuntu profile page:

```
http://askubuntu.com/users/9953/xubuntix
```

I have waited hours, and no error was displayed to me.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stand corrected. The verification server already does extract the relevant user id from the URL you provide. As such, even URL of

```
foo/bar/9953/whatever
```

would work properly because the `9953` is correctly extracted.

I was shared this relevant code of the id extraction:

```
userid = int(userurl.split("/")[-2])
```

Technically, having your username after the URL or not would make no difference and you would have gotten your trophies regardless.

From what I understand and explained to me from the devs, the verification script was probably down or bugged at the time of your writing. Changing your identification has caused the local daemon to re-send all the trophies for verification once again and luckily the server was fine this time around.

Comment: I have done so. waited 10min. restarted the computer. cklicked "Check accomplishments". waited 20min. Now I see the notification bubble with 'registered-on-askubuntu.trophy uploaded to your cloud'. But still, the 'My trophies' window is the same (no askubuntu anything). How long should I wait? Or is there anything else wrong?

Comment: @xubuntix It usually depends on what time the verification script runs. Give it about an hour or so. If you still don't receive any trophy, I would guess the server is at fault.

Comment: @xubuntix Answer is corrected now. The previous version was not accurate and had misinformation. I hope you understand that. :)

Comment: good to know :-)

Comment: one more thing: I can see some of the trophies now. But after more than one day, only half the badges show up...

Comment: @xubuntix Funny issue you have. I suggest you file a bug report against the project..